# Bluetooth Driver file corrupt or replaced

Tags: windows, bluetooth, driver

I have a config with a MSI Z690 Ace motherboard. I was using the motherboard bluetooth adapter to connect my bluetooth devices and everything was working great.

I then installed a Gigabyte WIFI 7 PCIE card (that is powered by a Qualcomm chip that also provides Bluetooth 5.4). When I installed the new Wifi/BT card drivers, bluetooth simply stopped working on my computer. It is working correctly in my Device Manager but it is not detecting any devices.

I then purchased a USB BT dongle. It is detected normally but doesn't detect any BT devices around me.

My assumptions is that my drivers (bth.inf or another file) have somehow been corrupted or replaced (many BT related files like bth.inf and bth.pnf have been modified recently according to Windows). I tried to uninstall them (didn't work). I wanted to delete the.inf file but even after modify the authorizations inside the security properties of the file, it is still impossible to rename/delete the files.

I don't know what to do.

Comment: i think this question better addressed on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) given you are not writing a driver. that aside, i do wonder if this a hardware issue?

Comment: Sorry didn't know SuperUser. I just posted it there.